# Fetching records and then putting in a new column

Tags: python, pandas, loops, if-statement

I am working with Pandas data frame for one of my projects.

I have a column name Count having integer values in that column.

I have 720 values for each hour i.e 24 * 30 days.

I want to run a loop which can get initially first 24 values from the data frame and put in a new column and then take the next 24 and put in the new column and then so on.

for example:

input:

```
34
45
76
87
98
34
```

output:

```
34   87
45   98
76   34
```

here it is a row of 6 and I am taking first 3 values and putting them in the first column and the next 3 in the 2nd one.

Can someone please help with writing a code/program for the same. It would be of great help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try `numpy`'s `reshape` method performed on `pd.Series.values`.

```
s = pd.Series(np.arange(720))
df = pd.DataFrame(s.values.reshape((30,24)).T)
```

Or [`split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) (specify how many arrays you want to split into),

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"day" + str(i): v for i, v in enumerate(np.split(s.values, 30))})
```

Comment: TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>

Comment: When I type my dataframe column in place of 720  as nf['Count'] . it gives me the following error :   TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>

Comment: also can you please let me know where in the 2nd example i can put in my column name as .... my dataframe is nf and column is Count

Comment: You should just use  `pd.DataFrame(nf['Court'].values.reshape((30,24)).T)`

Comment: `"day" + str(i)` this will be the column names in the second method. You can specify column names later on in method 1 as well.

Comment: Hi Tai, Thank you for the quick response .. pd.DataFrame(nf['Court'].values.reshape((30,24)).T) this one is working though , But I just have one more doubt actually  I working on preparing the script so at times the number of values can change. so how can i change the code in a way so that it suits up to all the values. I mean here 30,24 means that this is for the month which is having only 30 days and 24 hours is the same thing . but what if the month is of duration 31 days and or so. how can modify the code to make it work.

Comment: Also for the second df = pd.DataFrame({"day" + str(i): v for i, v in enumerate(np.split(s.values, 30))}) I dont know how to fix the code as in this case I am still getting the error. I have dataframe nf with column name count . Please let me know the modification I need to do to make it work. THanks again

Comment: You can let the reshape function infers how many days it has. Use reshape((-1, 24)). @NikhilSwami you should replace `s.values` with `nf["count"].values` in your second problem